# Deploy a Maven application in IntelliJ 12 without building with Maven

Tags: maven, deployment, configuration, intellij-idea, makefile

I have problem with configuration of maven project in IntelliJ. I deploy my application to JBoss, when I start JBoss server via IntelliJ, application is deployed without any additional actions, but when I try to redeploy application after some changes, IntelliJ try to make project with it's own make process, and it fails. I have to make project via maven and restart server to redeploy application. Can I somehow tell intelliJ to use maven while redeploy application? I cannot see such option in Run/Debug configuration window.

Comment: How are you deploying your application in JBoss the first time? You should configure your project such as there is no compilation error when you make it with IntelliJ's internal build system.

Comment: I have my war artifact in deployments tab in Run/Debug configuration window and when I start serwer the war file is just deployed without make action. I can add maven goal in deployment tab or as after/pre make actions, but it doesn't change make process.
While IntelliJ try to make project it gives me a lot of 'copying errors'

Comment: IntelliJ *has* to build the artifact before deploying it. It is normal that it does another make when you try to redeploy your app (you can't skip this part). It seems that the error you are getting is not directly related to IntelliJ, what is the exact message you are getting?

Comment: The automatic make is good think, but it will be nice if I can tell IntelliJ that it should be done via maven. When IntelliJ truies to run embeded make I have a lot of errors like this:
Error copying '(...)\game.war\target\game\WEB-INF\web.xml' to '(...)\game.ear\target\game\game.war\WEB-INF\web.xml'.: (...)\game.ear\target\game\game.war\WEB-INF\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using exploded artefacts (present icon) Server, Deployment Section. Right?
There you can choose the external artefact and disable the make flag.
I always using exploded artefacts, because of the hot code deployment. So I do no need to deploy artefacts again and again. 
Please be aware if there is already an artefact (e.g. foobar.war) in the same location (maven target directory), you have to change the name of the exploded artefact (e.g. foobarE.war). Idea is creating a folder named foobarE.war.